# SQL - Query if the same card exists among multiple decks

Tags: sql

Given the schema below, how can I query if and how many of the same character card is in multiple decks, without changing the underlying data?

```
CREATE TABLE 'deck' (
  'deckId' BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'title' TEXT(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('deckId')
);

CREATE TABLE 'character' (
  'characterId' BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'name' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('userId')
);

CREATE TABLE 'card' (
  'cardId' BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'color' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  'characterId' BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  'deckId' BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('cardId'),
  CONSTRAINT 'FK_card_character'
  FOREIGN KEY ('characterId')
  REFERENCES 'character' ('characterId'),
  CONSTRAINT 'FK_card_deck'
  FOREIGN KEY ('deckId')
  REFERENCES 'deck' ('deckId')
);
```

Comment: Could you [mcve] this? (Maybe this is already minimal; I'm no expert)

Comment: Your title is misleading, what you are asking for is the same card exists among multiple Decks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is this is a properly normalized schema.  So often the questions posed here involve bad database design.

Essentially you need to GROUP BY, and then use the HAVING clause.  The JOIN here is just cosmetic so you can get the Character name, but usually that is something people want.  When you are getting comfortable with this type of query you might want to start with just the underlying table, which in your case is card.

```
SELECT ch.characterId, ch.name, count(*) as countOf
FROM card ca
JOIN character ch ON ch.characterId = ca.characterId
GROUP BY ca.characterId
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```